# Search for byte pattern in node.js Buffer

Tags: node.js

I have this node.js Buffer.

```
var test_buf = "5E4D802158D002001022201022AB778899A1B2C3";
var buffer_hex = new Buffer(test_buf, "hex");
```

I want to search for the existence of byte pattern `77 88 99` in `buffer_hex`. From the tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_buffers.htm, I cannot find a suitable Buffer function to use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `buffer_hex.includes()` (or [`.indexOf()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_indexof_value_byteoffset_encoding) if you need the offset) to find a specific value inside of the buffer. `.includes()` accepts strings, numbers or other buffers:

Worth noting that `.includes()` is available since Node 5.3.0.

```
console.log(buffer_hex.includes("778899", 0, "hex")); // boolean
console.log(buffer_hex.indexOf("778899", 0, "hex")); // number
```

Please note that `new Buffer()` is deprecated since Node 6. You should use `Buffer.from()` instead for those versions.

Comment: I am using node v4.7, not v6. I am not sure if `Buffer.from` is supported in v4.x. Is it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.indexOf()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_indexof_value_byteoffset_encoding):

```
let included = buffer_hex.indexOf('778899', 0, 'hex') !== -1;
```